# How to loop through full API collection by changing one number in URL

Tags: python, json, api

I am using this API ('https://api.opensea.io/asset/0x5d00d312e171be5342067c09bae883f9bcb2003b/1/') to collect information about individual digital assets within a certain game. The '1' at the end of the URL represents the asset with token_id = 1. I am trying to get my code to collect the variables that I need for each asset and then cycle to the next - token_id = 2 which would be a '2' at the end of the URL, token_id = 3, and so on. The final asset would be token_id = 51,450.

I would like to print the results and then somehow export to excel if possible, been trying to figure that out as well. All help is appreciated, thanks!

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.opensea.io/asset/0x5d00d312e171be5342067c09bae883f9bcb2003b/1/')
EMONA_json = r.json()
EMONA_str = json.dumps(EMONA_json, indent=2)

token_id = EMONA_json['token_id']
traits = EMONA_json['traits']
owner_address = EMONA_json['owner']['address']

print(token_id, traits, owner_address)
```

Best case scenario - the code would print all the results into excel. Each column would include 'token_id', 'traits' (will eventually extract trait_type: class_name, level & catch_number values) and owner_address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple example that will hopefully guide you to a more refined and better solution.

In order to keep things easy I output results into a csv file that you can easily import in Excel.

```
import json
import requests
import csv

result = {}
max_id_to_get = 3

for token_id in range(1,max_id_to_get):
    r = requests.get('https://api.opensea.io/asset/0x5d00d312e171be5342067c09bae883f9bcb2003b/{}'.format(token_id))
    EMONA_json = r.json()
    EMONA_str = json.dumps(EMONA_json, indent=2)
    token_id = EMONA_json['token_id']
    traits = EMONA_json['traits']
    owner_address = EMONA_json['owner']['address']
    result[token_id] = {"traits":traits, "owner_address":owner_address}

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(["token_id", "traits", "owner_address"])
    for id in result:
        writer.writerow([id, result[id]['traits'], result[id]['owner_address']])
csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your question is how to handle 50000+ api calls, well here goes:

Use a queue ([RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) for example) which retries an event in case it fails. Create 50000 events (or maybe use batches) and sent them to the queue. A services will subscribe to this queue which will do the actual API call. This can be made in parallel. I would store resulting data in a NoSQL (key value or document), with the `token_id` as a hash key. Once all are done, scan that table and create the excel/csv file.